# php can't get into correct selected value from combobox

Tags: php, combobox

this is what I have::

```
     <form action="" method="post">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>"/>
 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Applicant ID:</strong> <?php echo $id; ?><br />
 <strong>Applicant name: </strong> 
 <input type="text" name="username" readonly value="<?php echo $lastname. "," . $firstname. " " .substr($middlename, 0,1); ?>"/><br/>
 <strong>Username: </strong><input type="text" readonly name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" /> <br />
 <strong>Password: </strong><input type="text" readonly name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" /> <br />

 <strong>Manage Application: </strong><select name="status">
  <?php
    $selection = array(
    0 => "Pending",
    1 => "Approve",
    2 => "Revoke" );


    foreach($selection as $key => $value)
    {
        echo '<option value="' . $key . '"';
        if ($status == $key)
        echo ' selected="selected"';
        echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
        echo ' <br />';
    }
?>
</select>
<br />

<button type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"><img src="../../images/login.png" />Update</button>

<?php 

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
if($value == 'Approve'){

$to = $_POST['email'];
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'BCE Scholars Application Notification';  
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Congratulations! Your application is approved."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: bcescholar@yahoo.com\r\nReply-To: bcescholar@yahoo.com";
//send the email
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo("<p>Congrats!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
}


if($value == 'Revoke')
{
$to = $_POST['email'];
//define the subject of the email
$subject = 'BCE Scholars Application Notification'; 
//define the message to be sent. Each line should be separated with \n
$message = "Sorry your application is revoked."; 
//define the headers we want passed. Note that they are separated with \r\n
$headers = "From: bcescholar@yahoo.com\r\nReply-To: bcescholar@yahoo.com";
//send the email
if (mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
echo("<p>Congrats!</p>");
} else {
echo("<p>Message delivery failed...</p>");
}
}


} // end of if button pressed

  ?>

 <a href="../index.php"><button type="button"><img src="../../images/back.png"/>Back</button></a>
 </div>
</form>
```

my site is sending an email notification to its applicants. If the admin selects the approve from the combobox, it will send automatically an email, otherwise will also send an email of notifying the applicant that his application has been revoked/rejected. But my problem is it's not getting into the APPROVE if ($value == 'Approve') statement..It's always getting into the REVOKE statement. What's wrong with this? Please help. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that `$value` is only accessable in your `foreach($selection as $key => $value)` loop, but you try to use it **outside of the loop**. You could save your values to a temp array to use them afterwards

**Example:**

```
$tempArray = array();
foreach($selection as $key => $value)
{
    echo '<option value="' . $key . '"';
    if ($status == $key)
    echo ' selected="selected"';
    echo '>' . $value . '</option>';
    echo ' <br />';
    $tempArray[] = $value;
}
```

Afterwards access it with:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($tempArray[]); $i++) {
   // do what you want sith $tempArray[$i];
}
```

**But I think what you want to do is**

`if($_POST['status'] == 1)` check if "Approve" was selected in your combobox

Comment: Hi can you show me how to save values to a temp array? thank you.

Comment: I read your code again, I think what you want to do is, check the selected value from combobox in your if statement right? Than just change your statement to `if($_POST['status'] == 1)`, `$_POST['status']` will have the id of the attribute from selected item in combobox. Another way would be to add `value` attribute to your options

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it!

since I save the status id of it, I changed to

```
    if($_POST['status'] == 1)
```

Thanks to all who helped!